# Webpack compiler failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-dom

I am new to react and webpack, I have an app that I want to import, and at the time of doing the bundle with the webpack the following error appears:

> *ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:16 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,
>   currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
>   Seehttps://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders | import * as serviceWorker
>   from '../src/serviceWorker'; |
>
> > ReactDOM.render (, document.getElementById ('root')); | | serviceWorker.unregister ();*

**My index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../src/index.css';
import App from '../src/App';
import * as serviceWorker from '../src/serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**My package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "cs": "^1.0.3",
    "css": "^2.2.4",
    "fsevents": "^2.0.7",
    "material-table": "^1.50.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I have tried to install every module to see if it works, but facing same issue.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi it means that your configuration needs to be updated and that you need to add an additional loader for your code to be compiled _You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type_

Comment: What is you extention on serviceWorker?

Comment: Do you mean the format?

Comment: Can you share how you run your build with webpack and if you have a webpack configuration it would be nice if you could share that es well.

Comment: I tried to run it with the command: "webpack" in order to create the bundle, i have not any webpack.config.js

Comment: @AidanCL85 yes, I mean format

Comment: My serviceworker is .JS format

Comment: try to change to .js